# Não consigo importar um arquivo no terminal usando o pyhton

Tags: python-3.x

Eu tenho um código bem simples no python na versão 3.9.0. Quando entro no terminal e na pasta em que está salvo o arquivo tento executar o seguinte comando no terminal import nome do arquivo e um erro aparece:

```
import : O termo 'import' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
No linha:1 caractere:1

+ import area_circunferencia_v1
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

O código chama-se area_circunferencia_v1.py e segue abaixo:

```
# ! python
from math import pi

def circulo(raio):
    return pi * float(raio)**2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raio = input('Informe o raio:')
    area = circulo(raio)
print('Área do círculo: ', area)
```

Comment: Se você está tentando executar um codigo .py pelo terminal(cmd) use: python area_circunferencia_v1.py

Comment: [Shebang](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) não funciona diretamente em Windows. Deve abrir o arquivo em shell com suporte a Posix para shebang ou então associar extensão *\*.py* com o interpretador.

Comment: na instalação foi setado as variaveis de ambiente, no cmd ao digitar python entra no shell interativo tentou usar o idle para ver se esta funcionando bem ?

Comment: Ele está tentando executar o arquivo automaticamente por duplo clique.

Comment: jeferson.cardoso ainda não tentei, vou tentar!